# how to refresh my office JS add-in side panel using javascript code?

Tags: javascript, office365, add-in

how to refresh my office JS add-in side panel using javascript code ? I want when when I click on on this button in my add-in side panel refresh my add-in side panel

```
   <button onclick="Refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: If the add-in uses web technologies, can't you just do it the usual way via [`reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very esay to refrsh your add-in on button click

```
<button onclick="Refresh()">Refresh</button>
 //js
 function Refresh(){
  location.reload();
 }
```